# Can a genetic algorithm optimize my NP-complete problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an array that stores a large collection of elements.
Any two elements can be *compared* in some function with the result being **true** or **false**.

The problem is to find the largest or at least a relatively large subgroup, where **every element with all the others in that subgroup is in a true relationship**.

Finding the largest subgroup from an array of size *N* requires *N!* operations, so the iterative way is out.

Randomly adding successive matching elements works, but the resulting subgroups are too small.

Can this problem be significantly optimised using a genetic algorithm and thus find much larger subgroups in a reasonable time?

Comment: Can you query all N choose 2 (= Theta(N^2)) pairs and then run a standard clique-finding algorithm like Bron--Kerbosch?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat
Bron-Kerbosch's time complexity of O(3^(N/3)) doesn't seem really right here. The array stores thousands or even millions of vertices. And again: I just need a quicker way of finding bigger cliques, not necessarily finding the biggest one

Comment: That's a worst-case running time. I've run BK on sparse graphs with millions of nodes before no problem.